# Change of sign and expected value over a PDF

Tags: probability

I have some doubts with the following issue.

Defining the expected value as usual:

$E[x] = \int dx \ x \ p(x)$

With $p(x)$ a normalized probability density function, can we say something about the expected value when we want to evaluate it over $p(-x)$?

Is it correct to say:

$\int dx \ x \ p(-x) = - \int dx \ x \ p(x)$

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you known change of variable?

Comment: What do you mean by "normalized probability density" ? Do you mean a law $\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma ^2)$ ?

Comment: I only mean that the integral of the pdf is equal to one: $\int \ p(x) \ dx = 1$

Comment: You mean that $p(x)$ is a **probability density function**.  ( A *normalising constant* is that by which an everywhere nonnegative function must be multiplied to ensure the integral over the real domain equal to one; which is a property any probability density function is required to have. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.   It's just a change of variable transformation.   Taking it one step at a time.
$$\begin{align}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} x\,p(−x)\operatorname d x~=~&-\int^{-\infty}_{\infty} x\,p(-x)\operatorname d(- x) \tag 1 \\[1ex] ~=~& \int_{\infty}^{-\infty} (-x)\,p(-x)\operatorname d (-x) \tag 2 \\[1ex] ~=~& \int_{\infty}^{-\infty} s\,p(s)\operatorname d s \tag 3 \\[1ex] ~=~& -\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} s\,p(s)\operatorname d s \tag 4 \\[1ex] ~=~& -\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} x\,p(x)\operatorname d x \tag 5 \\[1.5ex] ~=~& -\mathsf E(X) \tag 6\end{align}$$